# Difference in using "in" operator and dot notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a question that is just bothering me. If I declare a `var a` and I then try to test it using the "in" operator I get a true result, if I do the same test using the dot notation I get a false result, for example...

```
var a;

if('a' in window) {
  console.log('a in window'); // this is written to the console
}

if (window.a) {
  console.log('window.a'); // nothing happening here
}
```

now I noticed that when I give a a value like so both outputs work... look at this and notice how I check if it doesn't exist:

```
var a;

if('a' in window) {
  console.log('a in window'); // this is written to the console
}

if (!window.a) {
  console.log('!window.a'); // this is written to the console
}

a = 1;

if (window.a) {
  console.log('window.a'); // this is written to the console
}
```

So why does the dot notation only work when the variable is assigned a value? A silly question I know but so far I can't get a definite answer!

Comment: It's because `window.a` yeilds `undefined` - it evaulates to false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Johan pointed out, the check is getting a falsey value.

```
if ('a' in window) console.log("a exists");
if (window.a) console.log("window.a is a truthy value");
if (!window.a) console.log("window.a is a falsey value");
if (typeof window.a != "undefined") console.log("window.a is not undefined");
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.a` is `undefined` before you give it a value, and

```
if (undefined) === if (Boolean(undefined))
```

Since Boolean(undefined) === false, the `console.log` within your if statement is not reached.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your console and play like this:

```
var a;
```

> undefined

```
'a' in window
```

> true

```
window.a
```

> undefined

```
a = 1
```

> 1

```
window.a
```

> 1

```
'a' in window
```

> true

The `in` keyword checks if there is a variable in a context. So, an expression using `in`, will always return `true` or `false` based on its existence, not on its value.

The `.` notaction access the variable's value in a context. So, an expression using `.`, might return any value, including `undefined`, if it wasn't.

Now that you know what's being returned for each expression, mix it with what the evaluation done when each value is returned inside an if statement.

As you might know, `undefined` will evaluate to `false`, and both `1` and `true` will evaluate to true, resulting on the behavior you're facing.